# How create log4j wrap and get correct logs

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have multithreaded application and i want add some text information in every log message
I create factory and extend class, it works fine

```
...
protected Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("Test", new MyLog4JFactory());
...

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggerFactory;

public class MyLog4JFactory implements LoggerFactory{
    @Override
    public Logger makeNewLoggerInstance(String arg0) {
        return new MyLogger(arg0);
    }

}


import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
public class MyLogger extends Logger{
    protected MyLogger(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
    private String getMessage(Object msg){
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        return sb.append(msg).append(" ").append("My text").toString();
    }
    @Override
    public void debug(Object message) {
        super.debug(getMessage(message));
    }
    @Override
    public void error(Object message) {
        super.error(getMessage(message));
    }
    @Override
    public void fatal(Object message) {
        super.fatal(getMessage(message));
    }
    @Override
    public void info(Object message) {
        super.info(getMessage(message));
    }
    @Override
    public void warn(Object message) {
        super.warn(getMessage(message));
    }
}
```

but! in the logs I see the wrapper class

all logs print as

> 2011-09-08 10:45:49,359 DEBUG **MyLogger** (35) - Test1 My text

What should I do to the log file shows a classes (with line number) calls my logger?

Comment: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html

Comment: Hy! Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I would like to share a nice solution I found:

Add FQCN to your class,
call Logger.log method and pass it your FQCN
like so:

```
public class MyLogger extends Logger{
    private static String FQCN = MyLogger.class.getName();
    ...

    @Override
    public void debug(Object message) {
        super.log(FQCN, org.apache.log4j.Level.DEBUG,message, null);
    }


    @Override
    public void debug(Object message,Throwable t) {
        super.log(FQCN, org.apache.log4j.Level.DEBUG,message, t);
    }
}
```

(same will work for creating a wrapper...)

Answer (score 0):

In your log4j.properties file, remove the `%l` specifier from the line that looks something like this:

```
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=<...>
```

`ConversionPattern` could be `PatternLayout` or something else. This will prevent the fully qualified calling class name and line number from being displayed.

More information on the specifiers can be found [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html).

Comment: I don't use %l. Here my pattern "log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p %C{1} (%L) - %m%n"

Comment: Remove `%C{1} (%L)` to remove the calling class and line number.